# Tkinter - How can I get the system display settings (scale option) in order to adjust the scale of my icons properly?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scale, image-scaling

In these days I realized that there is an issue with my GUI created with Tkinter and the system display settings (scale option).

If you change the display resolution, it's ok, because the pixel are always the same, but if you change the scale, it affects only the widgets that use text inside them. Imagines can talk better than thousand words:

[image]

Below the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

import io
import tksvg
from lxml import etree

import ctypes
from sys import platform

# resolution fix:
if platform == "win32":
    try:
        ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) # windows >= 8.1
    except:
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware() # windows <= 8.0

# my free svg icon:
dic_tool_bar={"start":'<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.3.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M73 39c-14.8-9.1-33.4-9.4-48.5-.9S0 62.6 0 80V432c0 17.4 9.4 33.4 24.5 41.9s33.7 8.1 48.5-.9L361 297c14.3-8.7 23-24.2 23-41s-8.7-32.2-23-41L73 39z"/></svg>'}

# function to use svg icon in Tkinter:
def svg_to_image(source, fill=None, scale_to_width=None, scale_to_height=None, scale=1):

    # parse xml data
    root = etree.fromstring(source)
    tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

    # set path fill color if provided
    if fill is not None:
        root.attrib["fill"] = fill

    imgdata = io.BytesIO()
    tree.write(imgdata)
    kw = {"data": imgdata.getvalue()}
    if scale_to_width:
        kw["scaletowidth"] = scale_to_width
    if scale_to_height:
        kw["scaletoheight"] = scale_to_height
    if scale != 1:
        kw["scale"] = scale

    return tksvg.SvgImage(**kw)

class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):

        self.parent=tk.Tk()
        self.parent.title("TEST")
        self.parent.minsize(350, 300)
        self.icon_color="#484848"
        self.default_font=("Segoe UI",9, "bold")
        
        self.obj_tool_bar=ToolBar(self)
        self.obj_tool_bar.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)
        
        self.parent.mainloop()

class ToolBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, mw):
        super().__init__(mw.parent)

        self["background"]="white"
        self.default_font=mw.default_font
        self.icon_color=mw.icon_color

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        
        self.name=tk.Label(self, anchor="w", background="white", text="TEST!!", font=(self.default_font))
        self.border_up=tk.Frame(self, background="#bfbfbf", highlightthickness=0)
        self.border_down=tk.Frame(self, background="#bfbfbf", highlightthickness=0)

        self.start_logo=svg_to_image(dic_tool_bar["start"], fill=self.icon_color, scale=0.035)
        self.start=tk.Button(self, relief="flat", borderwidth=0, background="white", activebackground="white", image=self.start_logo)

        self.border_up.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="new")
        self.name.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsw", padx=(4,4), pady=(2,2))
        self.start.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ens", ipadx=4)
        self.border_down.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky="sew")

# start
app=MainWindow()
```

How can I solve this issue? I saw other softwares (not written in Python) with a toolbar, and in all of them, with different kind of system scales, the icons resolution changed always properly. How can I reach the same behaviour with Tkinter?

In my example, I was thinking about to create a custom function to change the resolution of the `self.start_logo` in according with the system scale option, but.. How? To do that, I need to get the system scale value or something like that, .. how can I do that? Do you have some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the user can set the icon’s size manually using this command:

```
self.start_logo=svg_to_image(dic_tool_bar["start"], fill=self.icon_color, scale=0.035)
```

To automate the process, we can use the following function to determine the current DPI:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication as QApp

def get_dpi():
    dpi = 0
    with QApp([]) as app:
        dpi = app.screens()[0].physicalDotsPerInch()
    return dpi
```

You can read more about QApplication [in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QApplication.html) and [here](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-pyqt-window/) - note that many examples use sys.argv, but a simple empty list (as shown above) works just fine.

Then you can update your call to use the dpi to figure out the scale. Assuming the value from your question, 0.035, corresponds to normal dpi, you could scale this value by the computed dpi as a fraction of the baseline.

Comment: I don't understand exactly how to use the `call` method to accomplish my goal. In my example I just need to scale the icon `start_logo` in according with the system scale option. I can do that manually but the right scale value depend by the system one, and I don't know how to get this information. can you be more clear about your solution please? I really don't know how to solve this issue, on internet I can't find a solution.

Comment: @TurboC ah, I think I understand what you mean now, let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, I'm a little bit confised. please, tell me if I'm writing something wrong. to calculate the right scale in DPI I should impelement this calculation "DESKTOP DPI (SCALE 100%)":"0,035 DPI" = "NEW DESKTOP DPI (SCALE 175% FOR EXAMPLE)":X but there is an issue. your function returns me always the same value even if I change the system scale option (in Widnows are 100%, 125%, 150% and 175%).

Comment: it returns me a different value only when the display resolution changes, but I don't care about it, because I have the issue with the resolution of my icon, only when the system scale changes. so, how can I calculate the right scale for my icon when the systrem scale changes? in addition, if it's possible, I would like to reach this goal using Tkinter only. I don't like the idea to import PyQt5 when all my GUI works with Tkinter.